# Right using models in controllers?

Tags: magento-2.1, architecture

For example, I need to get special data from a table for prepare form-data to save (in controller). Currently I have a direct dependency for a model.

```
use Vendor\CustomerSurvey\Model\Survey;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class FormPost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

...

$data = $this->_survey->getSomething();
```

But I know what magento has special classes like Repository, Registry, Model, Data (setters & getters). I have a question: what to use in this case?

Comment: Please can you be little bit clear I didn't get this what you want ?

Comment: @Manish In what cases should be used Repository, Registry, Model, Data.